# rails テーブルのレコードをid毎合算して集計する→ランキングとして表示

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

rails初心者です。
以下のようなタレント(talent)の人気を登録するテーブル(popularitys)があったとします
select * from popularitys;

id |　user_id  |  talent_id | 
ーーーーーーーーーーーー
| 1 |　　　　　1 |　　　　　1 | 
| 2 |　　　　　3 |　　　　　1 | 
| 3 |　　　　　5 |　　　　　1 | 
| 4 |　　　　　2 |　　　　　2 | 
| 5 |　　　　　7 |　　　　　4 | 
| 6 |　　　　　9 |　　　　　2 | 
| 7 |　　　　　8 |　　　　　3 | 
| 8 |　　　　　6 |　　　　　4 |

テーブル内(popularitys)のtalent_idのid毎に合算(sum)しソートして以下のように表示結果を出したいと思ってます

1位 talent_id: 1 sum= 3
 2位 talent_id: 2 sum= 2
 2位 talent_id: 4 sum= 2
 3位 talent_id: 4 sum= 2
 4位 talent_id: 3 sum= 1

アドバイス頂けましたら幸いです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

※特定のidをカウントすることはできました。
 Popularity.where(talent_id: 1).count
 => 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Popularity.group(:talent_id).order('count_talent_id desc').count(:talent_id)
```

これで`talent_id`ごとの`count`が求まると思うので、適切に表示したい結果に加工すればよいと思います。

参考：

- [ActiveRecordでgroup byしてカウントをして、カウント数でorderする - 酒と泪とRubyとRailsと](http://morizyun.github.io/blog/count-order-active-record-rails/)
- [ruby on rails - "Order by" result of "group by" count? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131109/order-by-result-of-group-by-count)

Comment: 有難うございました！望む結果が出せました！